# Crashing the logging formatter?

Tags: python, logging

I have a logging component in my program.  The setup of the formatter is straightforward:

```
sh.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(message)s"))
```

I notice that my program is having problems.  After a certain point, the formatter reverts to the default configuration (i.e., ignores the formatting I supplied).  On closer inspection it seems that I am crashing it by sending a message that throws a UnicodeDecodeError when rendered in the string.  But, I can't seem to fix.

I wrapped the logging call:

```
try:
    my_logger.info(msg)
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    pass
```

Which "catches" the exception, but the logger is still pooched.

Any thoughts?

Comment: In the except block, please put `print(repr(msg))`. Then post the result. Maybe it would help us if we knew what the `repr` looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any idea what input is causing the `UnicodeDecodeError`?  Ample printing of variables would help!  If you want to move on upon receiving that error, you should wrap the calls to the formatter in a `try..except` block.

```
try:
    # log stuff
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    # handle the exception and move on
```

It would be helpful to see some more code and some of your input data to give you a more clear response.

Comment: I did that wrap exactly.  The error is caught, but the logger is still botched.

Comment: Perhaps a simple re-initialization of your formatter upon catching an exception?  It's hard to tell without seeing the exact cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: http://wiki.python.org/moin/UnicodeDecodeError.
You probably have some string that can't be decoded.

Answer (score 0):

A user of my product had this issue.  Go into logging/**init**.py and add some print statements to print the record.**dict**.  If you see unicode in the asctime that could be your issue.